# Undefined error Accessing Android Camera

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to Get my application to take a picture with a camera and then display this code to the user.I have tried to follow the phonegap api's perfectly and they don't work however when I use my code in the phonegap example and change the function names to what the phonegap example uses and run the example script it works perfectly fine . The code I am using is

```
function gotoPicture() {

    if (/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        try {
            alert("test2");
            navigator.camera.getPicture(setImage,onError,{sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,quality:60});
        } //try
        catch (e) {
            alert("onerror")
            alert(e.Message);//test
        } //catch
    } //if
    else {
        $.mobile.changePage('#expense-page-picture');
    } //else
} //gotoPicture
```

The setImage and onError code are as follows

```
function onError(error) {
    alert("test1")
    navigator.notification.alert(error, null, "Error");
}

function setImage(imageData) {
    alert("test3")
    artificialReceipt = imageData;
    /* document.getElementById('expense-form-picture').src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + artificialReceipt; */
   document.getElementById('expense-form-picture').src = artificialReceipt;     // with cordova 1.5.0, it seems that imageData is a file location
    $.mobile.changePage('#expense-page-picture');
}
```

I get the onerror alert that is in the catch I never get the test1 alert I will also try adding the onDeviceReady and see if that makes a difference I believe I have tried that before 
I also added this above the code and nothing happened

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady()
{
    alert("i am ready");
}
```

never got the alert I am ready.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure you're using your function after deviceready event?

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
```

Then, can we see the setImage function and onError?
Can we have the responses? 
In setImage, you should have an image argument and onError, a message :

```
function setImage(image) {
    console.log(image);
}

function onError(message) {
    console.log('error:' + message);
}
```

Also, are you getting the 'onerror' alert?